# Provider with argument and navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am new to provider and using this [template](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a133148221a8cbacbcef8bc77a6c82ec).

How to add arguments (compareMe and context) to the class Counter and navigate to new screen?

```
class Counter with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  int _count = 0;
  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    if (_count == compareMe) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewScreen()),
      );
    } else {
      _count++;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer updated based on comments.*

You should listen to changes using Providers `Consumer` widget:

```dart
Consumer<Counter>(
              builder: (context, counter, child) {
                if (counter.count == counter.compareMe) {
                  // Delaying the navigation to make sure we have `context` available
                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),
                    );
                  });
                }
                return Text('${counter.count}');
              },
            ),
```

You full code will look like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Counter(compareMe: 5),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Consumer<Counter>(
              builder: (context, counter, child) {
                if (counter.count == counter.compareMe) {
                  // Delaying the navigation to make sure we have `context` available
                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),
                    );
                  });
                }
                return Text('${counter.count}');
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false).increment();
              },
              child: Text('Increment'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('new Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;
  int get count => _count;

  final int compareMe;

  Counter({required this.compareMe});

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

Not sure I understand/it's unclear your end goal. However, adding the arguments to `Counter` is simple: Accept the fields for `compareMe` and `context` in the constructor

```dart
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;

  int compareMe;
  BuildContext context;
  int get count => _count;
  Counter({required this.compareMe, required this.context});
```

Usage:

```dart
class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    // call the counter with the parameters you need
    final counter = Counter(compareMe: 5, context: context);
    // Do something with `counter`...

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Screen'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('New Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Or, when initialzing the Provider:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
  create: (context) => Counter(compareMe: 5, context: context),
  child: MyWidget(),
)
```

Comment: Hi @MendelG  Thanks.  My goal is to monitor the counter.  When counter = compareMe, it will go to new screen.  I tried your suggestion but not sure how to use compareMe for class Counter [link](https://ibb.co/rM8xn8F)

Comment: @DollyStorey I updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: ,Thanks.Exactly what I am looking for. Will ask again if encounter new issues.